# What does "not far wrong" mean?

Tags: meaning, past-tense, present-perfect

First, what does the sentence below mean?

> He may not have been far wrong

Second, why do we use *have* rather than *has*?

Comment: "*may*" is what is called a modal verb, the verb that follows is in the infinitive (without the "to") *He may be late*; *He may visit his relatives* etc. In your sentence, the tense is in the present perfect, i.e `have been`. *I/you/he/we/they may have been late*; *I (etc.) may have visited my relatives*

Comment: Is this a real question? This is a question asked in Mathematics/logic test.

Comment: What does it mean the sentence "He may not have been far wrong". really i do not know, is it meaning that he is wrong

Comment: http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/not%20far%20wrong/out/off  Someone or something that is not far wrong, not far out, or not far off is almost correct or almost accurate.

Comment: i must thank you for your help "mplungjan"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question first, **as Mari-Lou A has already explained**, "may" (just as "must", "can", "should", etc) is a modal verb and, as such, must be followed by infinitive.

As for your sentence "He may not have been far wrong", "far" is an adverb here.

> far (adv.) - to a great extent, much [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/far)
>
> - That car is far more expensive than ...
> - He is able to function far better than usual.
> - He felt far better yesterday.

So, your sentence means that "**probably he wasn't so wrong**"

Comment: I really appreciate  your help. thanks "Centaurus"